# Cannot access web application (Internet Explorer Can Not find this Page) remotely

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have Deployed my Asp.net web application on IIS 7.0  on localMachine(Server) and it is working fine there.

But when i try to access it from other machine in LAN, It gives me error that, *'Internet Explorer Can Not find this Page.'*

I am accessing it on terminals using server name address and also tried using IP address.
Even I have Shared the Application Folder in network.

Comment: Can you reword the title with a more descriptive title?

Comment: Done...I suspect English is not Bhusha's first language, so I'm helping out

Answer (score 0):

Check the Windows Firewall on your Vista PC. You need to let TCP port 80 through.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you [enable the firewall](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2007/10/17/i-can-only-access-vista-iis7-sites-from-localhost.aspx) and [bind to IP addresses other than localhost](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb734869.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to and should not share the application folder.
This is a security risk as people on the network will be able to access the source code of the application. Also, it won't help with the problems you're having because a network share is not accessed over HTTP and so will never hit IIS and your web application. So you can turn off sharing for the folder and be safe in the knowledge that this isn't the issue.

Next, check your windows firewall and make sure incomming web trafic is allowed ("http" or "port 80").

Next I would have a [look at the host headers](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=IIS7+configure+host+headers&meta=) that the site is running on.

Then maybe update your question with more detail.

Greg

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to ensure that IIS is listening on the correct IP Address. This problem can occur if you switch from a LAN connection to a wireless connection (for example when taking a work laptop home).

To Check this, open inetmgr and right-click on the 'Default Web Site' node. Verify that the IP Address entry is set to the current IP of your machine.